# Mysql couldn't write to /tmp then failed to restart

Tags: mysql

I was running `orthomcl` program which uses `mysql`. This program has operated just fine on the same computer before. This time I had an error message.

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_700_1.MYI' (Errcode: 13) at /usr/local/bioinf/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/bin/orthomclPairs line 709, <F> line 14.
```

I tried to restart `mysql` server, the server shut off but failed to start.

```
sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

`/var/log/mysql/error.log` and `/var/log/mysql.err` are empty. I've tried a few things that I found here including purging and reinstalling `mysql-server` and removing `ib_logfile*` in `/var/lib/mysql`.

The other thing I tried is

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

The error messages are:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibNzqwO0' (Errcode: 13)
InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Here are some information from `dmesg | grep mysql`:

```
[3115187.338273] init: mysql main process (44255) terminated with status 1
[3115187.338417] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[3115187.356361] init: mysql post-start process (44256) terminated with status 1
[3116827.473256] type=1400 audit(1396394069.224:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=45387 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/tmp/" pid=45396 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[3116827.582489] type=1400 audit(1396394069.332:133): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=45387 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/tmp/#sql_b154_0.MYI" pid=45402 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[3116827.908448] type=1400 audit(1396394069.660:134): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=45317 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/tmp/ibbPfaqP" pid=45415 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=118 ouid=118
[3116841.623608] type=1400 audit(1396394083.372:139): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=45443 comm="apparmor_parser"
[3116841.771621] init: mysql pre-start process (45474) terminated with status 1
```

There were many many lines like this.

Could anybody help me figure out what's wrong with my MySQL server, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The reason for this is that your `/tmp` is symlinked to another location, `/home/tmp`. But MySQL is armored by AppArmor, which does not allow writing freely to `/home/tmp`. To remedy the situation, you can edit the `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-tmp` and add the `/home/tmp` there appropriately; for me the extra lines

```
  owner /home/tmp/**    rwkl,
  /home/tmp/            rw,
```

did the trick.

Comment: Perfect! Solved the issue right away. I was sure it had something to do with the symlink!

Comment: I  had to restart apparmor for the changes to take effect: `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart`

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you don't have the right permissions on `/tmp`, which should be world writable. You should be able to fix it with this command:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

That will set the permissions to `777` (rwx for everyone) and also set the sticky bit which is recommended for the `/tmp` dir. As explained in `man chmod`:

> RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT
>
> The  restricted  deletion  flag  or  sticky  bit is a single bit, whose
>   interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it  prevents
>   unprivileged  users  from  removing or renaming a file in the directory
>   unless they  own  the  file  or  the  directory;  this  is  called  the
>   restricted  deletion  flag  for the directory, and is commonly found on
>   world-writable directories like /tmp.  For regular files on some  older
>   systems,  the  bit saves the program's text image on the swap device so
>   it will load more quickly when run; this is called the sticky bit.

Comment: @ScottSeverance please don't change code to quotes just for change's sake. Yes I know I was quoting but the code block gives better formatting and respects the header and indent. The way you edited it, everything is on the same line.

Comment: I changed it because when it's formatted as code I can't read it on my phone without constant horizontal scrolling.  There really is no benefit to formatting a quote as code. If you don't like the heading being on the same line, there are ways of fixing that without breaking the displays of users on phones.

Comment: @ScottSeverance ah, fair enough, I hadn't realized it caused problems on phones. OK, I'll put it in a quote block then. I was just annoyed because your edit (with no explanation) looks worse on normal browsers and you didn't check that it renders correctly. And you just edited again and it's perfect, thanks!

Comment: Mine is the correct solution. Mysql is apparmored and the apparmor does not like the `/tmp` being moved to another location without changing the confs. The audits tell that it is not the matter of permission denied on filesystem, but the apparmor guards.